# C program with fifo is not working, Unix console waits for input

Tags: c, shell, unix, fifo

I want to make a simple program that uses fifo. I compiled this code and when I run it the console is waiting for an input. I tried to put a printf on first line and it doesn t appear on console.

```c
int main(){
char* fifo = "./f"; 
int x = mkfifo(fifo, 0700);
if ( x == -1){
    perror("error open");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
int f = open (fifo, O_WRONLY);
if ( f == -1){
    perror("error open");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
close(f);
unlink(fifo);
return 0;
}
```

In console I run it like this

```
./x
```

and nothing happens, just the cursor is going next line and is waiting for input.

Why is my program not running?

Comment: in the console you should run the process. The execution file is named x?

Comment: From the man page:

Once  you have created a FIFO special file in this way, any process can
       open it for reading or writing, in the same way as  an  ordinary  file.
       However,  it  has to be open at both ends simultaneously before you can
       proceed to do any input or output operations on it.  Opening a FIFO for
       reading  normally  blocks  until some other process opens the same FIFO
       for writing, and vice versa.  See fifo(7) for nonblocking  handling  of
       FIFO special files.

Comment: Sorry, what's your meaning for _Is not  working_?  Have you started it? do you expect something to happen that doesn't? Is it happening something that has surprised you?

Comment: Can you reformat your code to make it more readable, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `mkfifo()` man page:

> Opening a FIFO for reading normally blocks until some other process opens the same FIFO for writing, and vice versa.  See fifo(7) for nonblocking handling of FIFO special files.

So after your call to open(), your process is put on hold until another process opens the fifo with read access. Which in your case never happens.